# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2 - Installing Studio plug-in fails in Eclipse "Juno"

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Whenever I try to install IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2 on an Eclipse Juno Release I get the following error. Can you help me resolve?

> Software being installed: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201306140658
>   (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group
>   6.0.0.201306140658)   Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20130418_1206 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 8.0.0.v20130418_1206) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not
>   be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Rich Page Editor - Dojo extensions 1.1.200.v20130523_1421 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.dojo 1.1.200.v20130523_1421)
>       To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Dojo Web Tools 2.0.0.v20130523_1421 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.feature.feature.group
>   2.0.0.v20130523_1421)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.dojo [1.1.200.v20130523_1421]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 6.0.0.201306140658 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group
>   6.0.0.201306140658)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.feature.feature.group 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you are using *[Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2)* and not another variant of Eclipse.

- This then can also happen due to slow network - try again
- Additionally, verify you have this option checked: "Contact all update sites during install to find required software", in Help >> Install New Software...